# Help on choosing compatibility test for classification algoritm

Tags: classification, histogram, probability-distribution-function

I have designed an algorithm for classification and I need to add a suitability or compatibility test for accepting a signal as an input. Basically, not all signals are suitable for processing by my algorithm and I need to find out a way to avoid processing signals which do not apply to my conditions.

My conditions: I need signals to be like this one:
[image]

However, I would like to reject signals like the below.

[image]

However, I have many questions open like Are the probability functions the same? Which test can I perform? They look like a normal distribution but they look very similar and I thought I could use a test for normality like Lilliefors, but now looking at the probability functions, I don't know what to apply.

Which test for compatibility would you recommend?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at both signals, there seems to be some semi-periodic component in the *accepted* signal that you can use, for example by doing a correlation based analysis:

- Your bottom signal looks like white Gaussian noise (maybe not completely white or Gaussian though), so the autocorrelation, theoretically, should just be an impulse at lag 0. Of course that’s theory only, but you should see something similar.
- On the other hand, I bet the autocorrelation of the top signal will have some spikes at later lags.

**EDIT: Frequency domain approach**

Here's another idea: if the frequency content of your **signals of interest** (specifically, at the times where the signal is above the noise) is different from the frequency content of your **rejected signals**, then you can, in the frequency domain, look at the ratio of powers in different frequency bands.

I'd start by first looking at a [spectrogram](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/spectrogram.html) of both **accepted** and **rejected** signals to see which frequency bands, if any, you can use to differentiate between the two.

For example, for white gaussian noise, the ratio of powers between any two frequency bands should be close to 1. Your signal might have some frequency band where there's a lot more power than in the other bands, which would help you differentiate between accepted and rejected.

Without more info, I can't really help further...

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Never thought about an correlation analysis. Might be interesting to read about it and see if I can apply any of that. Regarding your comment of the top signal, yes, there are spikes at later lags, greater than [-100, +100]. They are very important since that is the meaningful part of the signal. Thanks for your comments I am going to read about the correlation analysis.

Comment: Just to make myself completely clear, the spikes I mentioned would be visible on the signal’s auto-correlation sequence, I’m NOT talking about spikes on the raw signal. Let me know if you need further help, happy to answer :)

Comment: Understood, I was thinking about the values in the probability density functions corresponding to the fast ripples, and spikes, in the raw signal but know I get you better. Thanks. I will not look at the information about correlation analysis and get back to you if I have any doubt if you don't mind.

Comment: @GGChe did you ever solve this?

Comment: Hello Jdip, your answer gave me reason to rethink the problem and you were right about the test of normality. It doesn't really makes sense given this signal features. What I am doing is reading about doing test of variance and normality and with that, select the evaluation criteria parameters that I can use for the algorithm performance evaluation. By now, pearson correlation coefficient is one of those. However, this is a huge world and it is difficult to get some clear.

Comment: @GGChe I edited my answer with a frequency domain approach. Have you looked at the frequency content of your signals?

Comment: Yes, actually I run a frequency analysis in the past of those signals and there are exclusively three frequency components with the most significant information in the signal and one of the options was working on the FFT, looking at those bands and forcing a power check at those frequencies. However, since I want to publish this in a high-quartile paper, I would like to perform statistical analysis and compatibility test since it is more in the state of the art. However I shall consider the option you proposed.